# Can you replicate from SQL Server 2012 to 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, sql-server-2012

Quick question: can you replicate a database from SQL Server 2012 to 2008 R2?

We currently have a push transactional replication setup from a SQL Server 2008 R2 database (publisher) to another 2008 R2 (subscriber). The publisher is controlled by a partner organisation that we work closely with, but we have little control over their infrastructure (other than the replication).

Our partner is upgrading their infrastructure to SQL Server 2012 - and as such we need to know if we will be forced to upgrade all or part of our solution to 2012 to follow suit.

Do we need to upgrade our subscriber SQL Server to 2012, or can we leave it as 2008 R2 and somehow configure it to subscribe to a 2012 replication?

Any information and/or references would be appreciated. We're in the process of coming up with a migration plan.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your 2008R2 subscriber, as long as the distributor and the publisher are one and the same instance (and it seems that they are, since you're running a push trans replication). Quote from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143699.aspx):

> A Subscriber to a transactional publication can be any version within two versions of the Publisher version. For example: a SQL Server 2005 Publisher can have Subscribers running SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 (including SQL Server 2008 R2), or SQL Server 2012; ***and a SQL Server 2012 Publisher can have Subscribers running SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008 (including SQL Server 2008 R2)***, or SQL Server 2012.

Probably you will have to reinitialize your subscription once the publisher upgrade is done. it would be preferable to not use any 2012 specific features or even to run the publisher database in 2008 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

2 versions back SQL replication:

- 8.0 for SQL Server 2000.
- 9.0 for SQL Server 2005.
- 10.0 for SQL Server 2008.
- 10.5 for SQL Server 2008 R2.
- 11.0 for SQL Server 2012.
- 12.0 for SQL Server 2014.
- 13.0 for SQL Server 2016